# Is there a way to solve the dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/default.conf" not found: not found

can anyone help me with this please

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, @Nilk Nika. The right way to ask a question would be to provide as many details as you can so that others can understand it better. Here are a few suggestions: Start with a context of the problem, state what you tried so far, then what command you ran which gave the error, provide the full traceback for the error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you named your Dockerfile as 'Dockerfile' and not something like dockerfile or DockerFile etc.
If yes please share the daemon logs.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the current path where you create the docker image does not have a default.conf file, you can create a default.conf file that meets your requirements.